# Using Azure Managed Identity for app deployed to Azure?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-keyvault

I have an azure function app that will be deployed to azure. In this app, I have some secrets which are stored in Key Vault which I need to make use of using Azure Managed Identity. I have the following method in one of my classes which retrieves the secrets stored on KeyVault.

```
public static string GetSecretValue(string secretkey)
        {
            string keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_NAME");
            var kvUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";
            var secretclient = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            return secretclient.GetSecret(secretkey).Value.Value;
        }
```

I have an environment variable which stores my Key vault name as shown in the code. What I need is to check if my steps are correct in order to use Azure Managed Identity to retrieve the values of the 5 secrets stored in KeyVault during production/deployment to Azure and make sure everything works well (Note that when running locally everything works perfectly).

What I did so far is the following:

1- Enabled Managed Identities for Azure Function App

2- Grant Permission to Azure Function (selecting it as a user principal) to access KeyVault

3- Configured the Azure Key Vault in Visual Studio based on the method shown above

My question am I missing something in the code above or in the steps in order to use Azure Managed Identities? Should I add anything else in the Application Settings on Azure or that is not necessary? Can I keep the Environment Variable the way it is shown or should I store it somewhere else on Azure ?

Comment: If it works correctly locally, that implies your code is more or less correct (as `DefaultAzureCredential` would use a browser login to get a credential, and you mentioned that it works). Can you paste a screenshot into your question detailing the permissions you assigned to your managed identity's principal? Also, you might want to log that value with Application Insights, or some other logger so that you can see if there is a valid value there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested in my environment.

You need to add the application setting with the value as below for each secrets:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://my-key-vault.vault.azure.net/secrets/secretName/secretVersion)
```

[image]

You can find the secret Uri from the secret identifier of current version of the secret:

[image]

I called the secret using below line of code:

```
var secretValue = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("secret1", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

I am able to fetch the key vault secrets successfully

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. That really helped a lot. I just have a small question. In my situation the code in Visual Studio can either be set to release mode or debug in the configuration manager. How will I know in which mode will it be published to Azure ?

Comment: You can see here in what mode, you published your function from vs > build > publish selection: https://i.imgur.com/Ll4Q9XW.png

Comment: Thank you so much. I accepted your answer. One final question please, as you can see in the method above, I have stored locally an environment variable called KEY_VAULT_NAME. When publishing should I remove that environment variable? Or should I keep it ? In case, I should remove it, how will I be able to retrieve the values of the secrets based on the method above when the application is published ? And if the app was published and I wanted to modify it again locally how will I be able to do that ? Should it re-published, how is that done ? Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: You can keep/change the env variable locally as it won't affect the KeyVault operations in the azure function app.